# Elastic Search not executing search command

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search (and Kibana) v 6.3.0.  I am unable to obtain search results through the `RestHighLevelClient` that appear using Kibana.  Here are the steps to reproduce by issue, please let me know what you think.

1. Using the transport client I submit

   ```
   CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new 
   CreateIndexRequest("phenotype");
   Settings settings = Settings.builder()
               .put("index.number_of_replicas", 2)
               .put("index.number_of_shards", 3)
               .build();
   createIndexRequest.settings(settings);
   CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = 
   transportClient.admin().indices().create(createIndexRequest).actionGet();
   ```
2. Then I submit a mapping update for a field name called `key1` giving it the field type `keyword`.  Using the Kibana Dev Tools tab and the command `GET /phenotype/_mappings` I can verify that both steps 1 and 2 are successful.
3. I save a document to Elastic Search with the command `IndexResponse indexResponse = elasticSearchRepository.save(document1);` which contains only the information `key1: value1`.
4. Executing the command, from Kibana,

   ```
   GET /phenotype/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "term" : {
         "key1" : {
           "value" : "value1",
           "boost" : 1.0
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

I see that the correct data is returned, being

```
    {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "phenotype",
            "_type": "phenotype",
            "_id": "685c3d59-4315-4f63-bf6a-17ad8a20aede",
            "_score": 0.2876821,
            "_source": {
              "key1": "value1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

5. But when I execute the search command through the Java REST API I receive zero search hits.  This is how I do it.

   ```
   SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
       .query(
             QueryBuilders.termQuery("key1", "value1")
       );
   SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("phenotype");
   searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
   return restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
   ```

WHY?!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the REST client a little bit, but not much searching (yet!). I'm sure you've already looked, but [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html) is a guide for using the Search API.

I've found that sometimes the HighLevel client doesn't have as much functionality as I can get from just sending JSON data. If you're having problems with the High level client, you're able to access the Low Level client via `highlevelclient.getLowLevelClient()`. You can then call `performRequestAsync(method, endpoint, params, entity, responseListener)`

Here's an untested version using the raw JSON that you've posted, hopefully it will work (or give you a good idea):

```
    public void search(String index)
    {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"query\": {\n" +
                "    \"term\" : {\n" +
                "      \"key1\" : {\n" +
                "        \"value\" : \"value1\",\n" +
                "        \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // I'm not sure if you'll need '/phenotype/_search' or if just 'phenotype/_search' will suffice
        _highLevelClient.getLowLevelClient().performRequestAsync("GET", "phenotype/_search", 
                                     Collections.emptyMap(), entity, new ResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess (Response response) {
                // Get your data from the response
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Blake.  I'll give that a shot on Monday and get back to you.  :)

Comment: Blake.  Thanks for your awesome help.  The solution was to sleep for 1 second after saving the document to ES, before searching for it.  I feel like this is more of a bug on the ES side than anything else, so I am reluctant to mark your response as "the solution" to my problem.  It is distressing that the ES `save` method returns `Rest.CREATED` when I still need to sleep.  Thoughts?

Comment: You  may want to go to their github and ask that question. I agree that that's a bit concerning. Glad you found the solution though!